# Method does nothing if called within an if, if called directly from on event it works

Tags: java, math, discord-jda

I`m building a discord bot with jda, made a method to use mXparser to get a math operation as an input from the chat e.g: /math 5+1
wrote everything to get the message, separate the arguments from the input on the chat, everything works until I put the code inside an IF statement that checks if it actually starts with "/math", the code inside it uses mXparser to calculate everything and send it back to chat.

Tried just about everything I could think of, taking all variables off the method, rewriting everything, I don`t get any errors either as stack trace or in the code editor, it just doesnt go through, tried just printing everything and it works fine as well, printing all the values on the console, everything seems to be right.

This part is where I check for the message, get the Strings and trim everything

```java
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
    this.messageReceived = event;
    this.prefix = Main.prefix;

    checkPrefix = messageReceived.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("\\s" + prefix);
    mainArg = checkPrefix[0];
    checkArgs = messageReceived.getMessage().getContentRaw().split(" ");

    callAllCommands();
}
```

Here is the command to take the actual expression from the chat input calculate it and send it back.

```java
private void mathCommand() {
    mathexp = new Expression(checkArgs[1]);
    messageReceived.getChannel().sendTyping().queue();
    essageReceived.getChannel().sendMessage(Double.toString(mathexp.calculate())).queue();      
}
```

This is inside the `callAllCommands()` method, that is how it is supposed to work, if the command on the chat is `/math` then the expression e.g: `/math 1+1` it will send the result back, if I take off the IF statement it works just fine but then I can't check for the command. The other commands do work fine with the IF statement

```java
if (mainArg.contentEquals(prefix + "math")) {
    mathCommand();
}
```

I don't really get any errors, it just does not work, sorry if I missed something really simple, i`m not that experienced yet.

Comment: and you are sure that `mainArg` is exactly equal to `prefix + "math"`? maybe a trailing space, or even the whole formula is included? Or, is the prefix included in `MainArg`  seems like it is obtained from `split("\\s" = prefix)` that would **not** include the prefix in the result

Comment: anyway *recommended* to post a [mcve] - we can only guess what is inside the variables/constants - and you can be sure that `if` works in Java.... so for sure either `mainArg.contentEqual(prefix + "math")` is returning `false` (why are you not using `equals`?) or the `mathCommand()` is being called (we also do not know how you know that it is not) **or** the whole `if` statement is not being called at all

Comment: I do get the prefix along with the command with `checkPrefix[0]`, `mainArg` does include the prefix.

Comment: then `split` is not splitting... if you are using `split(prefix)` - `prefix` will **not** be included in the results. `"a:b:c".split(":")` returns `{ "a", "b", "c"}` (acredite ou teste)

Comment: If I try running `checkPrefix = messageReceived.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("\\s" + prefix);
  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(checkPrefix));`
then inputting _/math_ 1+1 in the chat I do get **[/math 1+1]** in the console with the prefix though

Comment: I`ll edit it with a more reproducible example, thank you for answering.

Comment: as I wrote it is not splitting, and why not output `mainArg`, the one involved in the test - based on above output, `mainArg` is `"/math 1+1"`, and **NOT**  `"/math"` <<maybe try `split("\\s")`, without `prefix`- or`split("\\s+")` to avoid multiple spaces>>

Comment: Ohh, I understand what you're saying now, it's getting the entire chat message, whilst it should be getting only `/math`, I understand it now, thank you very much.

Comment: It works now using `"\\s+"`, thank you very much for helping and explaining, how can you I mark it as answered now?

Comment: you can't - it is just a comment